# make a RESTful JSON request

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

What does it mean `make a RESTful JSON request.`?
Here the  context of the phrase:

[Backbone.sync](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) is the function that Backbone calls every time it attempts to read or save a model to the server. By default, it uses (jQuery/Zepto).ajax to make a RESTful JSON request.

Answer (score 3):

If you've never heard of REST before, I recommend reading up on it. It is a style of software architecture for systems, most often used in the context of HTTP requests and responses between the client and application layers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

So a RESTful JSON request will usually be an AJAX call that sends a GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE request to a URI along with relevant data and/or parameters. And the content would contain JSON, so the content type is application/json.

Comment: REST has nothing to do with the synchronous nature of the request.

Comment: I meant in this context, how it's typically used and what it means to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Representational State Transfer (RESTful) is the practice of requesting data from semantic and meaningful addresses, typically URL addresses on the web, regardless of actual directory structure on the responding server.

If I were to make a RESTful request for music on a music website the request may look something like:

http://examplemusic.com/Coldplay/Parachutes/Yellow/

The request is semantic in that it is meaningful to human consumption both literally and structurally.  The example states a domain, a music band, one of their albums, and a song from that album.  It is likely that the server has to perform extra work to provide such an address opposed to a more literal location on the server's directory structure relative to the web root.

To say that something is making a RESTful JSON request implies that the request is itself semantic and that the requesting content is a JSON data instance.

Comment: You never mention the http verbs which are a massive part of the rest service. How would you create a new record? Update the current? Synchronicity has nothing to do with REST (in fact I can make synchronous or asynchronous REST calls). It is, however, a great police album